# How do platelets produce proteins (if they do)?

Tags: cell-biology

I'm aware that platelets don't contain a nucleus, but do contain mitochondria (so have mtDNA) and rough endoplasmic reticulum / Golgi. Since platelets require many important cell surface proteins (such as aIIb b3 for ECM binding), are these proteins (1) synthesized de novo in the mitochondria using mtDNA, and then somehow shuttled to the ER / Golgi for secretion, (2) remnants from proteins that were synthesized in their megakaryocyte precursors and not actually created anew, or (3) synthesized via some other mechanism I'm not aware of? Online sources weren't clear on this question. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

it seems that megakaryocytes, while nucleated, create a large dormant reserve of mRNA and ribosomes, which can be used by platelets later, upon their activation. So platelets can synthesize only certain proteins already transcribed by their megakaryocyte predecessors. The reserve of mRNA decline with the platelet age.

Comment: Specific references would really improve this answer.

Comment: Please include references; even the best of answers are useless without resources to allow other users to background-read on your topics